# ModalBottomSheetLayout compose expanded and half expanded states

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I would like to open the bottom sheet in the expanded state when the button is clicked. But also when collapsed, it stopped in the half expanded state.

I used to do it like this:

```
sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

now we have updated the version of the material

```
androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.2
```

`animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)` method has become `internal` and cannot be called

now I am forced to use `sheetState.show()` but bottomsheet when opened gets `half expanded` state

to solve this added `skipHalfExpanded = true`

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
        confirmValueChange = {
            true
        },
        skipHalfExpanded = true
    )
```

Because of this, I no longer get the `half expanded` state

how can I get the expanded and half expanded states, but at the same time, when opening the bottom sheet by clicking on the button, so that there is always an expanded state